# Need two separate tables but EF 6 is creating only one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Contractor class and a Musicians Class which inherits the Contractor class. I am running migration and it will only build one Contractor table with Musicians fields included. I want a Contractor table and Musicians table that follows my domain models. It creates Instrument table correctly. Does this have something to do with the fact I am using inheritance on the classes?

```
 public class Contractor
{

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
    public string Email { get; set; }      
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }        
    public string Phone { get; set; }          
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SuspendDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }

}

 public class Musician : Contractor
{
    public Guid MusiciansId { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteLink { get; set; }      
    public string YouTubeLink { get; set; }      
    public string SoundCloudLink { get; set; }
    public string  ReverbNationLink { get; set; }
    public int YearsOfExperience { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime NextDateAvailable { get; set; }

    public Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }

    public Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
    public Guid ContractorId { get; set; }


}
```

My Migration script :

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Contractor",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                    Email = c.String(),
                    ZipCode = c.String(),
                    Phone = c.String(),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    SuspendDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ImageData = c.Binary(),
                    ImageMimeType = c.String(),
                    ImageName = c.String(),
                    Suspended = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    UnionMember = c.Boolean(),
                    MusiciansId = c.Guid(),
                    WebsiteLink = c.String(),
                    YouTubeLink = c.String(),
                    SoundCloudLink = c.String(),
                    ReverbNationLink = c.String(),
                    YearsOfExperience = c.Int(),
                    NextDateAvailable = c.DateTime(),
                    InstrumentId = c.Int(),
                    ContractorId = c.Guid(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Contractor", t => t.ContractorId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Instrument", t => t.InstrumentId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.InstrumentId)
            .Index(t => t.ContractorId);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use inheritance in model classes.
You can add Type value for your Contractor and create another table for each type of contractor (Musician for example):

```
public enum ContractorType
{
    Musician = 0
}

public class Contractor
{

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
    public string Email { get; set; }      
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }        
    public string Phone { get; set; }          
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SuspendDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }

    public ContractorType contractorType { get; set; }
    public Musician Musician { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like the default for EF is TPH (Table per Hierarchy) inheritance. That creates just one table. There is an option of TPT (Table per type) that is not preferred because of complexity in table joins.  I got this from ASP.net site for the Contoso University tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research the answer is: [Table] attribute above Musicians class.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796521/Inheritance-in-Entity-Framework-Table-Per-Type